# Pandas slicing and indexing use with fillna

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe **tdf**
I am extracting a slice based on boolean labels

```
idx = tdf['MYcol1'] == 1
myslice = tdf.loc[idx] //I want myslice to be a view not a copy
```

Now i want to fill the missing values in a column of **myslice** and i want this to be reflected in **tdf** my original dataframe

```
myslice.loc[:,'MYcol2'].fillna(myslice['MYcol2'].mean(), inplace = True) // 1
myslice.ix[:,'MYcol2'].fillna(myslice['MYcol2'].mean(), inplace = True) // 2
```

Both 1 and 2 above throw the warning that: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot do that. Once you assigned it to a new variable, it became a copy. You need to use the tedious version with `tdf.loc[idx, 'MYcol2']`.

Comment: This is a good question, and the given answer does not address it. The stipulation is 'slice based on boolean labels'. The accepted does not work when these stipulations are in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign it to a new variable, it creates a copy. The things you do after that are irrelevant. Consider this:

```
tdf
Out: 
          A         B         C
0       NaN  0.195070 -1.781563
1 -0.729045  0.196557  0.354758
2  0.616887  0.008628       NaN
3       NaN       NaN  0.037006
4  0.767902       NaN       NaN
5 -0.805627       NaN       NaN
6  1.133080       NaN -0.659892
7 -1.139802  0.784958 -0.554310
8 -0.470638 -0.216950       NaN
9 -0.392389 -3.046143  0.543312
idx = tdf['A'] > 0  
myslice = tdf.loc[idx]
```

Fill NaN's in myslice:

```
myslice.loc[:,'B'].fillna(myslice['B'].mean(), inplace = True)
C:\Anaconda3\envs\p3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:3191: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._update_inplace(new_data)

myslice
Out: 
          A         B         C
2  0.616887  0.008628       NaN
4  0.767902  0.008628       NaN
6  1.133080  0.008628 -0.659892

tdf
Out: 
          A         B         C
0       NaN  0.195070 -1.781563
1 -0.729045  0.196557  0.354758
2  0.616887  0.008628       NaN
3       NaN       NaN  0.037006
4  0.767902       NaN       NaN
5 -0.805627       NaN       NaN
6  1.133080       NaN -0.659892
7 -1.139802  0.784958 -0.554310
8 -0.470638 -0.216950       NaN
9 -0.392389 -3.046143  0.543312
```

It is not reflected in tdf, because:

```
myslice.is_copy
Out: <weakref at 0x000001CC842FD318; to 'DataFrame' at 0x000001CC8422D6A0>
```

If you change it to:

```
tdf.loc[:, 'B'].fillna(tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].mean(), inplace=True)

tdf
Out: 
          A         B         C
0       NaN  0.195070 -1.781563
1 -0.729045  0.196557  0.354758
2  0.616887  0.008628       NaN
3       NaN  0.008628  0.037006
4  0.767902  0.008628       NaN
5 -0.805627  0.008628       NaN
6  1.133080  0.008628 -0.659892
7 -1.139802  0.784958 -0.554310
8 -0.470638 -0.216950       NaN
9 -0.392389 -3.046143  0.543312
```

then it works. In the last part you can also use `myslice['B'].mean()` because you are not updating those values. But the left side should be the original DataFrame.

Comment: Thanks, so if there are multiple conditions and stuff i would have to write a long tedious line of code, is that it?

Comment: what if i wanted to fill only those which satisfy the condition,    tdf.loc[idx,'B'].fillna() is not doing it

Comment: You can save the conditions in a boolean mask (`mask = (df['A'] > 0) & (df['B'] < 0) | (df['C'] > 0.2)`) and use that mask in the operations.

Comment: You can use `tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].fillna(tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].mean(), inplace=True)` for the ones that satisfy the condition.

Comment: I tried, it did not work, if i fill all, it works, but if i use idx to fill only the satisfying ones, there is no warning but the values aren't filled either

Comment: Try removing the inplace parameter and assigning it back: `tdf.loc[idx, 'B'] = tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].fillna(tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].mean())`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121600/discussion-between-vikash-b-and-ayhan).

Comment: What about answering the question for the part 'sliced with boolean labels'. This answer does not address that key part of the question.

Comment: @rocksNwaves You mean if you also want to filter the left hand side with a boolean mask? You need to use assignment in that case (`tdf.loc[idx, 'B'] = tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].fillna(tdf.loc[idx, 'B'].mean())`). `__getitem__` does not guarantee that you get a view; that's why if you call `fillna` on a sliced DataFrame with `inplace=True` there is a risk that your operations are on the copy. It is not the case with `__setitem__` though. That's why it works when you do `df.loc[mask, col] = df.loc[mask, col].fillna(...)`.

Comment: Gotchya, that makes good sense. I was trying to understand how the docs warnings on indexing practices was relevant here, and your comment illustrates it well. Thank you.